# ViewPager cards inspired by Duolingo

Tags: android, android-viewpager

[This is my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgFI7.png)  I am a beginner in android development now I'm working on an application where i use `PagerAdapter` for `card view`, actually I refer this link https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/viewpagercards, I didn't get where to handle button.Please, anyone, help me to do this as I'm beginner and learner.

```
public class CardPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements CardAdapter {

private List<CardView> mViews;
private List<CardItem> mData;
private float mBaseElevation;
Context ctx;

public CardPagerAdapter() {
    mData = new ArrayList<>();
    mViews = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addCardItem(CardItem item) {
    mViews.add(null);
    mData.add(item);
}

public float getBaseElevation() {
    return mBaseElevation;
}

@Override
public CardView getCardViewAt(int position) {
    System.out.println("getPosition" + position);

    return mViews.get(position);

}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.adapter, container, false);
    container.addView(view);
    bind(mData.get(position), view);



    CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

    if (mBaseElevation == 0) {
        mBaseElevation = cardView.getCardElevation();
    }

    cardView.setMaxCardElevation(mBaseElevation * MAX_ELEVATION_FACTOR);
    mViews.set(position, cardView);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
    mViews.set(position, null);
}

private void bind(final CardItem item, View view) {
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    titleTextView.setText(item.getTitle());

}

}
```

This is the code

Comment: Do you want button click event inside on adapter?

Comment: As u seen in my screenshot i have button inside the card and i have 3 more similar cards and i want to give different actions  for each button inside the card.

Comment: I can understand.Based on the view position you can write your own logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="24dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/contentTextView"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_click"
                style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bookmark_24dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In CardPagerAdapter.java

```
public class CardPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements CardAdapter {
    Button btn_click;
    private List<CardView> mViews;
    private List<CardItem> mData;
    private float mBaseElevation;
    Context mContext;

    public CardPagerAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        mData = new ArrayList<>();
        mViews = new ArrayList<>();
        mContext = mainActivity;
    }

    public void addCardItem(CardItem item) {
        mViews.add(null);
        mData.add(item);
    }

    public float getBaseElevation() {
        return mBaseElevation;
    }

    @Override
    public CardView getCardViewAt(int position) {
        return mViews.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.adapter, container, false);
        container.addView(view);
        bind(mData.get(position), view);
        CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

        if (mBaseElevation == 0) {
            mBaseElevation = cardView.getCardElevation();
        }

        cardView.setMaxCardElevation(mBaseElevation * MAX_ELEVATION_FACTOR);
        mViews.set(position, cardView);

        btn_click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "List Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
        mViews.set(position, null);
    }

    private void bind(CardItem item, View view) {
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        TextView contentTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contentTextView);
        btn_click = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_click);

        titleTextView.setText(item.getTitle());
        contentTextView.setText(item.getText());

    }

}
```

You have to change add context in adapter.

MainActivity.java

```
    mCardAdapter = new CardPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this);
```

This will be helpful

Comment: when i write Button btn_click = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_click); this it didn,t get id nd i already provide in layout

Comment: <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_click"
                style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="Button" />

Comment: @VLearner i tested the sample its working based on the button selection it will show a `toast`. Agree on the answer.

Comment: @VLearner Declare button globally in the class as i declared

Comment: Can you help same github question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66423612/android-how-to-add-fragment-to-viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Is it the button you mean is in the card view? If that you mean, then.

From what i've seen in the link you refer to, then i looked into the sample.
https://github.com/rubensousa/ViewPagerCards/

The button is located in adapter.xml, but it still doesn't have id. You can give that button an id like:

```
android:id="@+id/card_button"
```

Then after that, you can handle the button by setting the click listener in the java class. For example:

```
Button theButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.card_button);

theButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        //The Action Here
                    }
                });
```

Hope this clear your problem.

Comment: Can you help same github question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66423612/android-how-to-add-fragment-to-viewpager